# Transfer a makeindex example to a xindy example

Tags: xindy

I use `makeindex` for 25 years and I know it isn't perfect. Since `xindy` is now available also for MiKTeX, I would be happy to switch to this more modern and flexible index processor. Now, I'm looking for a way to make legacy documents work with `xindy`.

For `makeindex`, I use a simple style file `german.ist` which changes `actual`, `quote` and `level` to operate with umlauts in `babel`:

```
actual '='
quote  '!'
level  '>'
```

I need to keep these changes also for `xindy` since I have a plethora of documents and macros which rely on these settings.

Here is a MWE of a working document with `makeindex`:

```
% compiled with pdflatex
\begin{filecontents*}{german.ist}
actual '='
quote  '!'
level  '>'
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s german.ist -g]

\begin{document}
Test
\index{a}\index{b}\index{"a}\index{"u}
\index{Bart}
\index{B"uro}
\index{Brause>gr"un}
\index{Bach}
\index{Ma"s}
\index{Burg=\textbf{Burg}}
\index{Buch|textbf}
\index{B"arte}
\index{B"ose}
\index{Brause>gelb}
\index{Blind}
\index{Brause}
\index{B"acker}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]

Now, I tried to adapt this example for `xindy`:

```
% compiled with pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-L german-duden -C latin1]

\begin{document}
Test
\index{a}\index{b}\index{"a}\index{"u}
\index{Bart}
\index{B"uro}
\index{Brause>gr"un}
\index{Bach}
\index{Ma"s}
\index{Burg=\textbf{Burg}}
\index{Buch|textbf}
\index{B"arte}
\index{B"ose}
\index{Brause>gelb}
\index{Blind}
\index{Brause}
\index{B"acker}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here, a counterpart of `german.ist` is missing. I get the following:

[image]

Could somebody help me to get the correct `xindy` configuration for this example?

Comment: Imho it is not possible (without recompiling xindy) to change the actual and quote character. Sadly xindy isn't perfect either. There are open problems regarding utf8, hyperref and the input. So probably you will have to preprocess the index argument before xindy sees it. E.g. xindy needs ` \index{B""uro}` so you could do something equivalent to `\appto\@sanitize{\shorthandon{"}\def"{\string"\string"}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is a pity. I had my fears about that, because I did not find anything before I asked the question. Currently, I also preprocess the index for makeindex to use 'real' umlauts and I hoped to get rid of that. Maybe, I better stay with makeindex for a while.

Comment: http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/faq-1.html, section 1.3. Our idx files are at first parsed by the program tex2xindy, that cannot be configured with different input specifiers. They say that you can modify the tex2xindy.l file and (easily?) compile it again. I don't know how to do that...