# How to put $!$ into index

Tags: indexing

I would like to use use index entry for factorial and i need to use $!$ in it. But exclamation mark is reserved for xindy to markup subitems, so this will not work

```
\index{*3*factorial@$!$ (factorial)}
```

What is a nice way to workaround it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character `!` is special for Xindy and MakeIndex: it serves for making subindex entries (unless modified with a style file for those programs).

In index context `"` is the escape char so use `\index{*3*factorial@$"!$ (factorial)}`

Comment: Since LaTeX writes the .idx file verbatim, I'd say it is the other way around.

Comment: @egreg how, certain chars are special in index context in LaTeX. Where did I get my wording wrong?

Comment: The `!` is by no means special for LaTeX. It is Xindy that considers it special.

Comment: @egreg it is also special in `makeindex` it is not just in `xindy`, that is what I'm refering to.

Comment: “Observe that `!` is special for MakeIndex and Xindy, so that `\index{a!b}` can be used for making a subitem; in this case you want to avoid that MakeIndex or Xindy interpret `!` in that way, so you need to escape it.”

Comment: Note that `!` could be changed into any character you wish, by means of a MakeIndex or Xindy style.

Comment: @egreg Sorry to ask, but how to change `!` into another character by a Xindy style? I know how to do this in a MakeIndex style, but I have no idea how to achieve this in a Xindy style. It looks contradict with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257191/transfer-a-makeindex-example-to-a-xindy-example

Comment: @Gau-Syu Sorry, I don't know. I'd go to the manual of Xindy, if it existed.